# How to define casts attribute without know their column laravel

Tags: laravel, casting, accessor

Im trying to make casts on Laravel 8, but i have a lot columns. is there a quick way without knowing the column ?
expected :

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = foreach($this->$attributes as $key) {
    $key => NullCast::class,
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, and I haven't thought about it enough to know if I'd even recommend it, but you could trying doing this loop in the constructor. You'd need to make sure you call the parent class constructor after you set the property.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, is it like this ?
`/**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $temp = array();
        foreach ($this->attributes as $key) {   
            $temp[$key] = NullCast::class;
        }
        $this->casts = $temp;
        parent::__construct();
    }`

Comment: but this doesn't work

Comment: `$this->attributes` is probably empty since the parent constructor hasn't been called yet... I'm not sure then. Is this just to save some typing? Or is there an actual reason why the attributes are unknown?